# Construction and validation of an index

Tags: references

We use different methods to construct indices for different things, say the Human Development Index, the Consumer Price Index, Democracy Index etc. These indices seem to have quite different methodologies.

If I want to have a proper introduction to the construction of indices, like what are the theoretical requirements that have to be fulfilled for something to be called an index, what are the various approaches currently in wide use to construct indices and their properties, and how are indices validated etc. what would be some good resources to read? I am looking for something like a textbook or handbook or even a collection of articles that can give me a comprehensive understanding of index construction.

Comment: Your apt remark about "different methodologies" is a strong hint that "index" can mean different things and be computed in different ways in different contexts for different purposes.  The central idea of this otherwise vague underlying concept is that an index serves as a *proxy* for or *summary* of a more complicated collection of variables.  Such proxies can be developed in myriad ways, ranging from seat-of-the-pants intuition (that's basically how most stock market indexes began) to regression models to correlation models to dimension-reduction algorithms. A textbook is unlikely to exist.

Comment: Got it, thank you